# Why is Ansible skipping the task even though the condition is correct?

Tags: ansible

Below is my code where I am looking for the value in file /home/xxx/logs/213079.txt and make the condition true or false.

```
  - name: register name
    shell: cat /home/xxx/213079.txt
    register: a213079

  - name: register output
    shell: cat /home/xxx/logs/213079.txt
    register: h213079

  - shell: echo {{ a213079.stdout }} Healthy >> /home/xxx/ABC/213079.txt
    when:
      - "'Serious' not in h213079.stdout"
      - "'Service' not in h213079.stdout"

  - shell: echo {{ a213079.stdout }} Faulty >> /home/xxx/ABC/213079.txt
    when:
      - "'Serious' in h213079.stdout"
      - "'Service' in h213079.stdout"
```

But when I am running the same, all the conditions are skipping.

```
TASK [tmp : register output] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [tmp : shell] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [tmp : shell] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [tmp : shell] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [tmp : shell] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [127.0.0.1]
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: Hi sachin kumar, welcome to SO. This sounds like a simple logic problem; what is your question about ansible?

Answer (score 0):

since we don't know the out-put you get this looks complicated but if you can grep the specific word i suggest you to use something like below.

when: h213079.stdout =! "Serious" and h213079.stdout=! "Service"

when: h213079.stdout == "Serious" and h213079.stdout== "Service"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking to get an output of system health when these 2 conditions are met. It should display "system xxx is Healthy if Serious/Service is not available in a h213079. else it should display that the system is Faulty.  I will try the above and will let you know how it goes

Comment: Sample logs file which I am referring is below: 
name=DB Drive
description=Service
name=DB Environment
description=Normal
name=DB Fan
description=Normal
name=DB Power Supply